# ksh: Defining a parameter name with another parameter's value

Tags: ksh

I have a ksh script that reads a profile script with a number of sessions defined. Each session defines its own parameters as such:

```
SESSION_ONE_USER=...
SESSION_ONE_PWD=...
SESSION_TWO_USER=...
...
```

The script gets the SESSION parameter from the command line, but I simply set it for the example.

I want to let the SESSION parameter value define part of another parameter name, that I need the value from, like:

```
SESSION="SESSION_ONE"
USER=${${SESSION}_USER}
PASS=${${SESSION}_PWD}
```

That gives me a compile error.
I also tried

```
GET_USER_PARAM(){
    echo ${SESSION}_USER
}
echo $`GET_USER_PARAM`
```

But that returns $SESSION_ONE_USER

I want it to return the value of the parameter SESSION_ONE_USER instead. 
Does anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `eval` is for:

```
SESSION=SESSION_ONE
eval echo \$${SESSION}_USER
```

should display the value of `$SESSION_ONE_USER`.

Comment: When assigning the value to a variable, i seemed to need to place the eval line in a function and call the function as SUSER=´SUFUNC´, otherwise it only returned the name. Still, this was exactly what i needed! Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't need a function. This seems to work for me: `SUSER=blah; TMP=USER; eval X=\$S${TMP}; echo ${X}` produces "blah". No quotes needed, but escaping the first `$` is necessary. Quotes would become necessary if the variable in question contained spaces, though, but you would want double quotes for that, and still escape the `$`...

Answer (score 1):

Don't monkey with variable names, use associative arrays instead

```
typeset -A users
typeset -A pwd

session=SESSION_ONE
users[$session]=joe
pwd[$session]=secret

for key in "${!users[@]}"; do
    echo "user for session $key is ${users[$key]}"
    echo "pwd  for session $key is ${pwd[$key]}"
done
```

Comment: It's a good idea. But i would need major changes in the remaining application to accomodate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SESSION="SESSION_ONE"
SESSION_ONE_USER="foo"
SESSION_ONE_PWD="bar"

SESSION_USER=${SESSION}_USER
SESSION_PWD=${SESSION}_PWD

USER=${!SESSION_USER}
PASS=${!SESSION_PWD}

echo $USER
echo $PASS
```

The "!" does a level of indirection. See [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: This works as well. I accepted te other answer only because it was fewer lines of code. (It was the only objective way i could think of)

Comment: Sure. Just keep in mind that this approach (parameter expansion) is just a bit more efficient (and standard). Good to know I guess. The other approach involves execution of two commands (echo and eval). These are internal, so it's quick. But parameter expansion is a faster path through the shell.

Comment: `bash` and `ksh` appear to differ here.  `ksh` just returns the name of the variable.  For arrays it returns the list of indexes, for associative arrays the list of keys.

Comment: @MartinNielsen Odd that you mention this works for you. Did you test it in `ksh`?

Answer (score 1):

If this is `ksh`, then this is a job for `nameref`

`alias nameref='typeset -n'`

**Example Solution**

```
function session_parameters { set -u
    typeset session=${1:?session name}
    nameref user=SESSION_${session}_USER
    nameref pass=SESSION_${session}_PASS
    print session=$session user=$user pass=$pass
}
SESSION_ONE_USER="User1"
SESSION_ONE_PASS="Pass1"
SESSION_TWO_USER="User2"
SESSION_TWO_PASS="Pass2"
for s in ONE TWO THREE; do
    session_parameters $s
done
```

**Sample output**

```
session=ONE user=User1 pass=Pass1
session=TWO user=User2 pass=Pass2
test_session_parameters[12]: session_parameters: line 5:
SESSION_THREE_USER: parameter not set
```

Note the usage of `set -u` to force the error message on line 3.

---

`nameref` usage: (from the builtin help text)

**NAME**

typeset - declare or display variables with attributes

**SYNOPSIS**

`typeset [ options ] [name[=value]...]`

`-n`
Name reference.

The value is the name of a variable that `name` references. `name`  cannot contain a `..`. Cannot be use with any other options.